# Does boron require chelation in alkaline soils

Tags: fertilizer, nutrients, irrigation

My soil test shows 0.4ppm Boron which puts its into the deficient category. I have few Mango seedlings and mature pear trees that show Boron deificiency. I tried foliar feeding but I would love to give some to the roots. I have an 8.4 pH. When applying Boron in fertigation should I be looking for a chelated form of the nutrient in my very alkaline soil?

Comment: Why not tell us about the problem not what you think is the solution? Is there a plant showing deficiencies?

Comment: @kevinskio I updated the topic, thanks for the suggestion.